# What are APEX limitation, Avantages, disavantages?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm new to Oracle APEX technologie, I would like some orientation over APEX, Avantages, disavantages and limitation from APEX seniors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

advantage /disadvantage early discussed refer 
[Advantages and disadvantages of APEX?](https://community.oracle.com/message/1215201)
and also refer [APEX LIMITS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/limits.htm#HTMDB28629)